# What are the differences between export and modules.export in ES

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sometime I see:
export default class ...

And

module.exports = ...

What are the differences? Which one we will use in which situation?

Comment: Haven't seen the answer

Answer (score 1):

*Just to clarify. This is specific to node.js*

Creating a module in node it is like you are wrapping it in a function like the one below. Actually, this is more or less what node is doing.

```
function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {

}
```

So, the exports variable is actually a reference to the module.exports and like that, you can have two variables pointing at the same object. The exports and the module.exports reference to the same spot in memory. You have to be a bit careful with the use of exports because there are some 'dark' parts that are connected with the javascript objects and there are some patterns that can break. Here is an example:

**dependency_exports.js**

```
exports = function () {
  console.log('dependency');
}
// Place console.log to see the contents of the exports and module.exports
console.log(exports);
console.log(module.exports);
```

**app.js**

```
var dependency = require('./dependency_exports');
dependency();
```

Why the two console.logs inside the dependency_exports.js file are printing different objects if they are pointing at the same memory? Remember that exports it is a reference to module.exports. 
When we assign another value to that variable (exports) we break the reference and a new spot in memory is created.
It does not update the reference inside the module.exports.

So now if we try to do something like that:

```
dependency();
```

We will see an error coming back, because of this issue.